# how i can subdivide object with blender python , i get error object mode to edit mode (Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, 3d, blender, mesh

```
import bpy
 
file_loc = 'mm_frame.obj'
 

imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_loc)
obj_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0] ####<--Fix

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=2)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")

bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.delete()
imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_loc)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=2)
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath="zetaxh.obj")
```

cant subdivide this please help me.
i need subdivide faces of object in python but i cant to go object mode to edit mode
i need help please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this code , thanks to all

```
import bpy
 
file_loc = 'mm_frame.obj'
 

imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_loc)
obj_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0] ####<--Fix

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=2)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")

bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.delete()
imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_loc)
 
obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[2]
print(obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj 


bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=2)
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath="zetaxh.obj")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).